# How to check matches between 2 arrays with foreach in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have an array of tags from my database. I also have attached tags from a current item. I want to check wether tags are already attached or not. This seems to work but of course I get duplicate items in my select-field when there is originally more than 1 tag attached to the item. How can I avoid this ?

```
<select name="tags" multiple required>
    @foreach ($tags as $name)
        @foreach($item->tags as $itemtag)
            @if($name == $itemtag->name)
                <option value="{{$name}}" selected>{{$name}}</option>
            @else
                <option value="{{$name}}">{{$name}}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**$tags array :**

```
 {"9":"Acoustic","3":"Angry","6":"Autumn","10":"Banjo","13":"Bass","14":"Cheerful","12":"Chill","35":"Dirty","8":"Electric","22":"Epiphone","24":"ESP","19":"Fender","33":"Funk","16":"Funny","18":"Gibson","30":"Gretsch","32":"Groovy","1":"Happy","20":"Ibanez","23":"Jackson","31":"Les Paul","28":"Martin","15":"Mellow","21":"Paul Reed Smith","27":"Redwood","2":"Sad","29":"Schecter","17":"Sleepy","34":"Spanish","7":"Spring","4":"Summer","26":"Taylor","11":"Ukulele","5":"Winter","25":"Yamaha"}
```

**$loop->tags array** :

```
[{"id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Happy","pivot":{"FK_loop_id":2,"FK_tag_id":1}},{"id":4,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Summer","pivot":{"FK_loop_id":2,"FK_tag_id":4}},{"id":14,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cheerful","pivot":{"FK_loop_id":2,"FK_tag_id":14}},{"id":9,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Acoustic","pivot":{"FK_loop_id":2,"FK_tag_id":9}}]
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the two array's data and the output you've currently got. I imagine the problem here is you don't have a key you can use to look up the tag name

Comment: just want to confirm that you don't want any duplicate record right ?

Comment: Yes that is right , this is actually to update the current items tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work :

```
<select name="tags" multiple required>
@foreach ($tags as $name)
    @foreach($item->tags as $itemtag)
        @if($name == $itemtag->name)
            <option value="{{$name}}" selected>{{$name}}</option>
            <?php continue 2; ?>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    <option value="{{$name}}">{{$name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This seems to work ! I would love to know an explanation of how this works :)

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, your question is still a bit confusing but the following code should do it I think:

```
<select name="tags" multiple required>
    @foreach($item->tags as $itemtag)
        @if(in_array($itemtag->name, $tags))
            <option value="{{$name}}" selected>{{$name}}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{$name}}">{{$name}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Basically all you want to check is that the name property is already in the array of tags so therefore you just need to use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the tag array has that value

Answer (score 1):

As i think this is good soluation provide by @Sofiene DJEBALI
I have 1 suggestion for this, using my suggestion you can complete this with only one foreach
-- Update your query and get only name with using pluck() function;
than your query result might be look like i.e $itemtag = array(Acoustic, Cheerful, Happy,Summer);
I am sure it take less time in processing

```
<select name="tags" multiple required>
  @foreach($tags as $key => $name)
    <option value="{{$key}}" <?php echo in_array($name, $itemtag)?'selected':'';?>>
     {{$name}}
   </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```